# "all the way (through)" and "to the end"

Tags: difference, idioms, phrases

> I haven't watched the movie **all the way through**.
>
> I haven't watched the movie **all the way**.
>
> I haven't watched the movie **all the way to the end**.
>
> I haven't watched the movie **to the end**.

Do all these sentences mean the same thing that the speaker hasn't finished watching the movie? Is the **through** redundant, would the sentence mean the same without it?

Comment: They're all fine, and almost always they would mean *exactly* the same thing. Stretching a point, if you'd seen the first half of the movie one night, then the second half sometime later, ***all the way through*** would work much better than ***[all the way [through]] to the end***. But that's a contrived/unlikely context.